# Convert from .net rich textbox to tiny mce

Tags: php, .net, tinymce, richtextbox

Currently I need to transform data from .net rich textbox which have some data as below :

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}
{\f1\fnil\fcharset204 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fi-360\li720\sb120\sa120
\qj\f0\fs20 2-   The workers demand that the company provide one free meal 
to those workers required to work overtime on holidays or Sundays (as the company never 
provide this to them). The company states that it will not provide 
this to those workers volunteer to work on holidays or Sunday because they work for only 
8 hours. \f1\fs18\par}
```

This data is not understand by tinymce and I think It may have tool to convert from the format of .net rich textbox to standard html.

Thank for your kind help,

Comment: no, tinymce is not able to understand this you will have to stick with pure html code

Comment: Yes .. I understand tinymce is not able the above data but I just wanna know if anyone got the same problem to convert data from rich textbox to tinymce or not? I can't find the solution ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the following link

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?8168-How-to-convert-contents-of-Rich-Text-Box-To-HTML

or use google

https://www.google.de/search?q=Convert+from+.net+rich+textbox+to+HTMl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a